# How to use a Webhook url with Paystack and send values to Database

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using https://github.com/iamraphson/vue-paystack in my laravel+vue SPA project. I can receive payments perfectly but now need to hit a webhook url so that I can update database and give value to user. I have set up the route and added the url on my paystack dashboard. What should I do next? How do I get the charge events and other details in my controller method and send to database?

I have tried the following in my controller:

```
    public function payme(Request $request){
         //This receives the webhook

    //$email = json_decode($input['data']['customer']['email']);
    $email = $request->input('data.customer.email');
    $bankname = $request->input('data.gateway_response');
      //$bankname = json_decode($input['data']['gateway_response']);
    $user = User::where('email', $email);

    $user->bankname = $bankname;
    $user->save();

    return response()->json('processed', 200);
```

Comment: i would suggest to you to use this library https://github.com/spatie/laravel-webhook-client ... I'm currently using it and it's perfectly scalable, it's easy to use and to understand and it works fine

Comment: Thanks @AlbertoSinigaglia! I have tried the recommended package but I could not get it to work for my use case.I guess it's just my inadequacy. I would appreciate specific guidance such that I implement as stated here: https://developers.paystack.co/v2.0/docs/events. Thanks again!

Comment: what can't you can implement in that package?